# Understanding the Warp Stabilizer mechanics and settings meaning

Tags: stabilisation, premiere-pro

I have a question for Adobe Premier Pro experts. There was a need to stabilize the video, and I faced a problem: I strongly do not understand the logic of settings and the mechanics of the Warp Stabilazer effect. I imagined it this way: there is a 'Smoothness' parameter that is responsible for the degree of stabilization, and which, I thought, directly affects the degree of crop: more 'Smoothness' is stronger than crop, less 'Smoothness' is less than crop, zero 'Smoothness' is the original frame size (no stabilization). I imagined the mechanics of the process something like this: a crop is made to some size (say, let there be a decrease of 22% of the original size), then the stabilizer moves and turns this crop so that the image that got into it changes as smoothly as possible, but at the same time so that the crop does not go beyond the original image. Then, if you set the 'Framing' parameter to "Stabilize, Crop, Auto-scale," as I thought, the croped stabilized picture is scaled to the original dimensions so that there are no black borders. However, in practice, it turned out that Warp Stabilazer behaves completely different from what I expected, and also has many not quite obvious settings. I got the following unexpected result:

[image]

Accordingly, I do not understand:

1. How does 'Smoothness' relate to the size of the crop?
2. How does the 'Crop Less <-> Smooth More' parameter relate to the 'Smoothness' parameter itself, and how does it, in turn, affect the crop?
3. What does the 'Preserve Scale' parameter really do with the selected "Position, Scale, Rotation" method? Does this mean that when the checkmark is removed, the amount (scale) of the crop will "float" throughout the timeline, thereby creating the effect of an ever-changing focal length? Or what scale is then preserved here?
4. Why did the crop at the specified parameters in the picture turn out to be so huge, at the specified 'Maximum Scale' value of 122%?
5. Why does the value of "Stabilize, Crop, Auto-scale" not scale the picture so as to get rid of black borders?

And here is what I have so far unsuccessfully tried to get:

1. constant crop by a given value (22%) with keeping of the aspect ratio.
2. maximum stabilization by the method of turns and paranomization with a given crop.
3. increasing the stabilized picture to its original size so that there are no black borders.

If anyone can clarify all this to me I would be very grateful. I myself could not find anything intelligible stuff on this topic...

P.S. Sorry for my not perfect English. And don't judge me strongly - I'm noob at the Adobe Premiere Pro.